# Detect doubleclick on ROW of TableView JavaFX 2

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

I've been looking around and have noticed the response given on this post:
[Detect doubleclick on row of TableView JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563390/detect-doubleclick-on-row-of-tableview-javafx)

However, this post uses lambda expressions and I'm unsure how to convert these to be used in JavaFX 2 code. My main goal is to be able to click a row, and then pop up a new window that has the information that was stored in that row. As long as I can get the Callback working, I will be able to take it from there! Any advice would be appreciated.

```
table.setRowFactory( tv -> {
    TableRow<MyType> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (! row.isEmpty()) ) {
            MyType rowData = row.getItem();
            System.out.println(rowData);
        }
    });
    return row ;
 });
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563390/detect-doubleclick-on-row-of-tableview-javafx.

Comment: I saw! But the answer does not work for javaFX 2.

Comment: Then update to javafx-8.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<MyType> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                MyType rowData = row.getItem();
                System.out.println(rowData);
            }
        }
    });
    return row;
});
```

Depending on your IDE you can usually hit ctrl + space when the cursor is in the parentheses of `setOnMouseClicked()` and it will tell you what it takes. Then you can type `new EventHandler` (or whatever it needs), hit enter and most IDEs will autocomplete the full method for you. Then you can just paste in the guts.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use this way to solve the problem

```
@FXML
     public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
         
             if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                  TableView.TableViewSelectionModel<Pessoa> p = tableFamilia.getSelectionModel();
                   System.out.println(p.getSelectedItem().getNome());
             }
           
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Full solution

```
 @FXML
private TableView<StudentTableModel> studentTable;

....
studentTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<StudentTableModel> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                    TableView.TableViewSelectionModel<StudentTableModel> rowData = studentTable.getSelectionModel();
                    editOnDoubleClick(rowData.getSelectedItem());
                }
            }
        });
        return row;
    });
```

It took me a while searching for this and i this really helped me give a more intuitive UX on my JavaFX application.

Hope it helps someone.