# Selecting a TableColumn within a Tableview to open a Form

Tags: javafx

I'm ultizling javafx to code a GUI. I have a table that has two different appointments. Each appointment type has a specific visitTypeId. I have the data setup like this --

```
 ObservableList<IAppointmentModel> initialData() {
        IAppointmentModel apt1 = new IAppointmentModel("10/31/2023", "Test Apt 1",1, "Dr. Smith");
        IAppointmentModel apt2 = new IAppointmentModel("2/8/2023", "Test Apt 2", 2, "Dr. Smith");
        return FXCollections.<IAppointmentModel>observableArrayList(apt1, apt2);
    }
```

This is then added to the table as such -

```
aptData.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<IAppointmentModel, String>("aptDate")));
    referringMd.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<IAppointmentModel, String>("referringMd")));
    visitType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<IAppointmentModel, String>("visitType"));
    tableView.setItems(initialData());
```

Then the table and columns are setup as -

The end users are able to right click on the apt and a context menu appears with an option to 'View Details'. Once the end user clicks on that option a form is opened and the form is different for the different appointment types. Example; Test Apt 1 appointment type would open FormA and Test Apt 2 would open FormB.

I've tried numerous different things to solve this issue.

```
viewButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            IAppointmentModel item = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            try {
                if(item.equals(visitTypeId.equals(1))){
                    Parent popUp;
                    popUp = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(GaitApplication.class.getResource("Visits/VisitDetailsGait.fxml")));
                    Stage stage1 = new Stage();
                    stage1.setTitle("GAIT Visit Details:   ");
                    stage1.setScene(new Scene(popUp, 800, 680));
                    stage1.show();
                }else if(item.equals(visitTypeId.equals(2))){
                    Parent popUp;
                    popUp = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(GaitApplication.class.getResource("Visits/VisitDetailsUE.fxml")));
                    Stage stage1 = new Stage();
                    stage1.setTitle("UE Visit Details:   ");
                    stage1.setScene(new Scene(popUp, 800, 680));
                    stage1.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

the viewButton is the context menu option to open the form. I created a setOnAction based on when that option is clicked. I created the variable item to note when a row is being selected and then an if statement to note what appointment is being selected. Currently, when select the view details option nothing happens.

I've also tried this too -

```
 viewButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            IAppointmentModel item = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            try {
                if(item.equals(visitType.getText().equals("Test Apt 1"))){
                    Parent popUp;
                    popUp = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(GaitApplication.class.getResource("Visits/FormA.fxml")));
                    Stage stage1 = new Stage();
                    stage1.setTitle("GAIT Visit Details:   ");
                    stage1.setScene(new Scene(popUp, 800, 680));
                    stage1.show();
                }else if(item.equals(visitType.getText().equals("Test Apt 2"))){
                    Parent popUp;
                    popUp = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(GaitApplication.class.getResource("Visits/FormB.fxml")));
                    Stage stage1 = new Stage();
                    stage1.setTitle("UE Visit Details:   ");
                    stage1.setScene(new Scene(popUp, 800, 680));
                    stage1.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Similiar to the above solution but I tried to use the String appointment type value within the if statement. When I click on the view details option this also does nothing.

Comment: This is really answered in a combination of different posts on this site, but the basics are: 1. Use a `rowFactory` on the table that creates a `TableRow` with the context menu registered. That way you can access the item for the row in the context menu event handlers. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565887/2189127) is similar, but use a context menu instead of the mouse listener. 2. Pass the item represented by the row to the controller for the details view. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: Did you mean "TableRow" in the question title, instead of "TableColumn"?

Comment: Off-topic: [do not use `PropertyValueFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437983/why-should-i-avoid-using-propertyvaluefactory-in-javafx-and-what-should-i-use-i)

Comment: I did mean to put TableColumn initially but I do think I mean TableRow now that I've read through your previous explanation. The value is in the row.. which yeah I wasn't thinking clearly.

Comment: Looking more closely at your code, what are you trying to achieve with `if(item.equals(visitTypeId.equals(1)))`? Since `item` is not a `Boolean`, this can never be `true`.

Comment: I was trying different solutions at this point. Within the my IAppointment class; I have a variable for visitTypeId. I was thinking that "Test Type 1" could be visitTypeId =1.Essentially I was trying to have theif statement look at the item(the selected item) and compare that to being equal the visitType = 1 or 2. I honestly forgot about enums until I had read your answer and did a little research on them. It's exactly what i needed in this case.

Comment: Why not do `if (item.getVisitType()==1)`?

Comment: that perhaps could work as well. the answer you provided below with the code works perfectly. thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really answered in a combination of different posts on this site, but the basics are:

1. Use a `rowFactory` on the table that creates a `TableRow` with the context menu registered. That way you can access the item for the row in the context menu event handlers. This is quite similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565887/2189127).
2. Pass the item represented by the row to the controller. This is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

The first is implemented something like this:

```
    table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<Appointment> row = new TableRow<>();
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem details = new MenuItem("Details...");
        details.setOnAction(e -> {
            showDetails(row.getItem());
        });
        menu.getItems().add(details);
        row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldAppointment, newAppointment) -> {
            if (newAppointment == null) {
                row.setContextMenu(null);
            } else {
                row.setContextMenu(menu);
            }
        });
        return row;
    });
```

with the helper method, which implements the second part:

```
private static void showDetails(Appointment appointment) {
    Parent root = null ;
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    try {
        switch (appointment.getType()) {
            case GAIT -> {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(VisitDetailsGaitController.class.getResource("VisitDetailsGait.fxml"));
                root = loader.load();
                VisitDetailsGaitController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setAppointment(appointment);
                stage.setTitle("GAIT appointment details");
            }
            case UE -> {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(VisitDetailsUEController.class.getResource("VisitDetailsUE.fxml"));
                root = loader.load();
                VisitDetailsUEController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setAppointment(appointment);
                stage.setTitle("UE appointment details");
            }

        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Appointment {

    public enum Type {GAIT, UE}

    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final ObjectProperty<Type> type = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final StringProperty doctor = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Appointment(LocalDate date, String name, Type type, String doctor) {
        setDate(date);
        setName(name);
        setType(type);
        setDoctor(doctor);
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date.set(date);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Type> typeProperty() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type.set(type);
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return doctor.get();
    }

    public StringProperty doctorProperty() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
        this.doctor.set(doctor);
    }
}
```

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AppointmentApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(AppointmentApplication.class.getResource("Appointments.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Appointments");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class AppointmentController {
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Appointment, String> nameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Appointment, LocalDate> dateCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Appointment, String> mdCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Appointment, Appointment.Type> typeCol;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Appointment> table ;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Appointment> row = new TableRow<>();
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem details = new MenuItem("Details...");
            details.setOnAction(e -> {
                showDetails(row.getItem());
            });
            menu.getItems().add(details);
            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldAppointment, newAppointment) -> {
                if (newAppointment == null) {
                    row.setContextMenu(null);
                } else {
                    row.setContextMenu(menu);
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().nameProperty());
        dateCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().dateProperty());
        mdCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().doctorProperty());
        typeCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().typeProperty());

        table.setItems(initialData());
    }

    private ObservableList<Appointment> initialData() {
        Appointment apt1 = new Appointment(LocalDate.of(2023, 10, 31), "Test Apt 1", Appointment.Type.GAIT, "Dr. Smith");
        Appointment apt2 = new Appointment(LocalDate.of(2023, 2, 8), "Test Apt 2", Appointment.Type.UE, "Dr. Smith");
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(apt1, apt2);
    }

    private static void showDetails(Appointment appointment) {
        Parent root = null ;
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        try {
            switch (appointment.getType()) {
                case GAIT -> {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(VisitDetailsGaitController.class.getResource("VisitDetailsGait.fxml"));
                    root = loader.load();
                    VisitDetailsGaitController controller = loader.getController();
                    controller.setAppointment(appointment);
                    stage.setTitle("GAIT appointment details");
                }
                case UE -> {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(VisitDetailsUEController.class.getResource("VisitDetailsUE.fxml"));
                    root = loader.load();
                    VisitDetailsUEController controller = loader.getController();
                    controller.setAppointment(appointment);
                    stage.setTitle("UE appointment details");
                }

            }
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

`Appointments.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.rowcontextmenu.AppointmentController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol" text="Appointment"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="dateCol" text="Appointment Date"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="mdCol" text="Referring MD"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="typeCol" text="Appointment Type"/>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

`VisitDetailsGait.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      alignment="CENTER"
      spacing="10"
      fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.rowcontextmenu.VisitDetailsGaitController">
    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="20"/></padding>
    <Label text="GAIT Appointment" style="-fx-font-size:24"/>
    <Label fx:id="nameLabel"/>
    <Label fx:id="dateLabel"/>
    <Label fx:id="mdLabel"/>
</VBox>
```

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;

public class VisitDetailsGaitController {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);

    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label dateLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label mdLabel;

    public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        nameLabel.setText(appointment.getName());
        dateLabel.setText(formatter.format(appointment.getDate()));
        mdLabel.setText(appointment.getDoctor());
    }
}
```

`VisitDetailsUE.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      alignment="CENTER"
      spacing="10"
      fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.rowcontextmenu.VisitDetailsUEController">
    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="20"/></padding>
    <Label text="UE Appointment" style="-fx-font-size:24"/>
    <Label fx:id="nameLabel"/>
    <Label fx:id="dateLabel"/>
    <Label fx:id="mdLabel"/>
</VBox>
```

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;

public class VisitDetailsUEController {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);

    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label dateLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label mdLabel;

    public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        nameLabel.setText(appointment.getName());
        dateLabel.setText(formatter.format(appointment.getDate()));
        mdLabel.setText(appointment.getDoctor());
    }
}
```